# TypeScript declarations for the Ace text editor

Tags: typescript, ace-editor

I am looking for TypeScript declaration files (*.d.ts) for the Ace text editor. Google didn't find anything. Has anybody seen them?

Comment: We don't have official ace.d.ts files but would accept pull requests for Ace

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I created the definitions. https://github.com/Diullei/ace-typescript-definition. When tests are correct I will send a pullrequest to [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped) and put the reference to definitions on http://www.tsdpm.com/

**EDITED**

I created the definitions. https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/ace/ace.d.ts http://www.tsdpm.com/

**EDITED 01-09-2017**

- The link has been moved to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/ace/index.d.ts
- *www.tsdpm.com* is no more available

Now using TypeScript 2.0+ you can install it directly from npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/ace

Comment: Great job, looks like a very thourogh definition

Comment: That link looks dead.  How about: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/ace

Comment: @MobyDisk thanks! The DefinitelyTyped repository has changed alot since this answer. I updated the answer with the new link.

Answer (score 3):

The top source for type definitions is [Definitely Typed on GitHub](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/).

They don't yet have one for Ace text editor, but I have an article on [writing types for TypeScript](http://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201301/Blog/Complex-TypeScript-Definitions-Made-Easy/) that may help.

If you want some help with it, break it down in chunks and ask on here and we'll help you.